# If else in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotus-formula

How to end if statment in lotus notes.

example.

```
@If(@Text(textbox1)="";@Failure("Please input your name");@Success);@command([filesave])
```

Comment: The closing parentheses ends the statement. It doesn't need anything else.

Answer (score 7):

You can end execution of formula statements by using @Return("").

Please read the documentation which is part of your Lotus Notes and Domino Designer clients. Look for the Help databases in the help folder of your Lotus Notes data directory.

Here's the online help for @Return: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_RETURN.html

Here's the online help for @If: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_IF.html

Answer (score 3):

You can skip @success afaik and try this:

```
@If(
    @Text(textbox1)="";
    @Failure("Please input your name");
    @command([filesave])
);
```

Another option is to use @do:

```
@If(
    @Text(textbox1)="";
    @Failure("Please input your name");
    @do(
        @success;
        @command([filesave])
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, @Failure is intended for use only in input validation formulas.

[Link to @Failure documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_FAILURE.html)

That article describes how it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the **failure** method by a simple prompt.

```
@If(
    @Text(textbox1)="";
    @prompt([OK],"Warning", "Please input your name");
    @command([filesave])
    );
```